# Animate Status Bar Color on DrawerLayout - Material Design

Tags: java, android

I'm writing a simple app that implements a material design compliant nav drawer as described by this Stack post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27153313/1621380

The `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout` works great and everything is dandy until I attempt to programmatically change the color of the status bar. My app uses the Palette API to change the toolbar and status bar color dynamically.

I'm using the [property animation api](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) to animate the toolbar and it works great! but I try to do the same animation on the statusbar and it doesn't seem to want to animate. Here's an example

[image: oh no statusbar!]

Here is the code for my animator:

```
public static void fadeStatusBar(final DrawerLayout layout, Integer from, Integer to) {
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), from, to);
        colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
                layout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor((Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue());
            }

        });
        colorAnimation.start();
    }
}
```

Note: That same code is fading the toolbar, so its proven to work.

My question is; does anyone know of a way to get a smooth transition when using `DrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgorundColour()`?

Note: I have used the Window method `window.setStatusBarColor()` method, and it animates fine but breaks the "transparent statusbar" when the NavDrawer is pulled in.

Comment: Note there's also the helper method [ValueAnimator.ofArgb()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#ofArgb(int...))

Comment: [DrawerLayout](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/lollipop-release/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.java#L1019) calculates the top inset and draws the status bar background itself. So, you just need to make a call to `View.invalidate` to force it to redraw while the animation is being updated.

Comment: @adneal That's wonderful and worked like a charm! Thank you

Comment: Great visualization to this question!

Answer (score 3):

As advised @adneal's comment on my original question the answer was to invalidate the view during the animation.

> DrawerLayout calculates the top inset and draws the status bar background itself. So, you just need to make a call to View.invalidate to force it to redraw while the animation is being updated. @adneal

I've updated my code to this

```
ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofArgb(from, to);
colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
        layout.invalidate();
        layout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor((Integer) animator.getAnimatedValue());
    }

});
colorAnimation.start();
```

For anyone wondering why this worked, I found this stack post enlightening: [When it's necessary to execute invalidate() on a View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647558/when-its-necessary-to-execute-invalidate-on-a-view)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this Easily like below:

---

1 - set your statusbar color to transparent by using this:

```
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

2 - define application's view to change it background:

```
View root = *A_view_on_the_activity*.getRootView();
```

3 - then add this function to your project:

```
private  void color_change(final View view,int from_color,int to_color){
    final float[] from = new float[3],
                    to =   new float[3];

    String hexColor_from = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & from_color));
    String hexColor_to = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & to_color));

    Color.colorToHSV(Color.parseColor(hexColor_from), from);   // from
    Color.colorToHSV(Color.parseColor(hexColor_to), to);     // to

    ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);   // animate from 0 to 1
    anim.setDuration(600);                              // for 300 ms

    final float[] hsv  = new float[3];                  // transition color
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener(){
        @Override public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            // Transition along each axis of HSV (hue, saturation, value)
            hsv[0] = from[0] + (to[0] - from[0])*animation.getAnimatedFraction();
            hsv[1] = from[1] + (to[1] - from[1])*animation.getAnimatedFraction();
            hsv[2] = from[2] + (to[2] - from[2])*animation.getAnimatedFraction();

            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.HSVToColor(hsv));
        }
    });

    anim.start();
}
```

4 - and then change the hole application's background color animation by using the function that Written above:

```
color_change(root, from_color, to_color);
```