# Animating multiple views causes animations to freeze

Tags: android, xml, animation, kotlin

I have a simple animation that makes a view go from one side of the screen to the other and its defined in the anim folder as `left_to_right.xml`:

```xml
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="true">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="-300%" android:toXDelta="360%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="3200"/>

</set>
```

What I want is to have multiple views sliding across the screen at the same time but different speeds, so I have 2 more xmls called `left_to_right_fast.xml` and `left_to_right_slow.xml` which are the exact same except for a different duration.

So in my view class I have these methods to create a image of a stripe and animate it, and when the animation is done, I remove it and make another:

```
    private fun doAStripe() {
        if (!isRunning) return

        val stripe = makeStripe()

        stripeHolder.addView(stripe)

        stripe.animation.onAnimationEnd {
            (stripe.parent as ViewGroup).removeView(stripe)

            doAStripe()
        }

        stripe.animate()
    }

    private fun makeStripe(): AppCompatImageView {
        val imageView = AppCompatImageView(context)

        imageView.layoutParams = LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT)

        imageView.setImageResource(listOf(R.drawable.cp_stripe_blue, R.drawable.cp_stripe_gray, R.drawable.cp_stripe_red).random())

        imageView.clearAnimation()

        imageView.animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, listOf(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.left_to_right_fast, R.anim.left_to_right_slow).random())

        imageView.x = width / 2f
        imageView.y = (0..(stripeHolder.height)).random().toFloat()

        return imageView
    }
```

So when I just call `doAStripe()` it works as expected, a stripe slides across the screen, and repeats.

But I want to be able to have multiple stripes going at the same time, so I try calling `doAStripe()` three times in a row, but when I do that - the stripes all seem to animate across the screen the first time but when the reappear they don't move, sit still for a couple seconds then disappears and new stripes appear to replace them.

So it seems like the animation is happening since the `onAnimationEnd` is getting called... but its not actually happening. Anyone know the reason for this?

Also my `onAnimationEnd` is just this convenience extension:

```
fun Animation.onAnimationEnd(callback: () -> Unit) {
    setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(p0: Animation?) {
        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(p0: Animation?) {
            callback()
        }

        override fun onAnimationStart(p0: Animation?) {
        }
    })
}
```

Update: [Here is a git repo with a demo project showing the bug](https://github.com/Doophie/StripesSuck)

you'll notice if you make onCreate only call `doAStripe()` once it works great, but call it more than once - and it works well for a couple stripes then starts freezing the animations.

Comment: what exactly you want to do is that 

having three view with animation that go left and right 

with different speed ? right ? but you want it to get repeat ? or you also want ? a pause between animation ?

Comment: @ArbazPirwani I want three views going at the same time, and each of them repeating with no pause in-between.

Comment: A sample on Github would be great so we can test your real code...

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS unfortunatley the real code is in a giant private repo for my work and I'm not allowed to make it public. Perhaps ill make a demo app shortly and give a link to that.

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Just made a git repo which has an example of the bug, updated the question

Comment: Why are you calling `doAStripe()` twice?

Comment: Also you are not using isRunning, I mean you are not setting to true or false never

Comment: I'm calling it twice because I want more than 1 stripe going at a time. and yes isRunning is not used in the example app, it was used in the app I copied this code from but wasn't relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do a little hack to do the two animations run at the same time, but well I followed your repository and I tested and yes, it looks laggy, the thing is, if you control the `Animation` inside a `Handler` `Android` will treat the threading for you, and there is one problem with your implementation, all of those animation were on the `MainThread` and this causes laggy.

So I ended up doing this :

```
private fun doAStripe() {
    val stripe = makeStripe()
    stripeHolder.addView(stripe)
    stripe.postDelayed({
        (stripe.parent as ViewGroup).removeView(stripe)
        doAStripe()
    }, stripe.animation.duration)
    stripe.animate().withLayer()
}
```

It looks smoothie, but not much fast, maybe you can control it with the `anim` files.

I also added `withLayer()`

> it enables hardware animations for all views you subsequently add to the animation.

Also added `imageView.invalidate()` in your `makeStripe()` method, to invalidate the `ImageView`. For more information you can read this [When it's necessary to execute invalidate on a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647558/when-its-necessary-to-execute-invalidate-on-a-view)

This is a simple demo how it looks :

https://vimeo.com/334493212

This is not the best option, but, well, the problem it self is not correctly stated at all, so, if I have more time I'll go deeper to check it out, but from now, the problem of "freeze" is gone.